# I'm using Perl to extract data from the following text data (text that look like this: ), I need to filter out data over linebreak but it doesn't work

Tags: regex, perl

I'm using Perl to extract/reformat text from the following text data:

```
Bryggkaffe  6 st    27,67 kr    166,03 kr

Blandfärs
"Behöver ca 3 kg köttfärs. sv"  3 kg    66,69 kr    200,07 kr 

Banan EKO   6 kg    22,54 kr    135,23 kr
```

I want

```
Blandfärs

"Behöver ca 3 kg köttfärs. sv"  3 kg    66,69 kr    200,07 kr
```

to become

```
Blandfärs 3 kg  66,69 kr    200,07 kr
```

There is something between the two rows, but it is impossible to capture with Perl, any suggestions (have already used/tested .  \f \r \n [x0A] [x0D])???

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below Perl one-liner command.

```
$ cat file
Bryggkaffe  6 st    27,67 kr    166,03 kr

Blandfärs
"Behöver ca 3 kg köttfärs. sv"  3 kg    66,69 kr    200,07 kr 

Banan EKO   6 kg    22,54 kr    135,23 kr
$ perl -0777pe 's/\n+"[^"]*"//g' file
Bryggkaffe  6 st    27,67 kr    166,03 kr

Blandfärs  3 kg    66,69 kr    200,07 kr 

Banan EKO   6 kg    22,54 kr    135,23 kr
```

**OR**

```
perl -00pe 's/\n+"[^"]*"//g' file
```

Comment: or `perl -0777pe 's/[\r\n]*\n[\r\n]*"[^"]*"//g' file` or `perl -00pe 's/\n+"[^"]*"//g' file`

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil that's why i added an alternative in comment.

Comment: I had to look this up, but the `-0777` option is the convention for [slurping a whole input](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches).  It sets the input separator to an impossible value which forces perl to real the whole input in one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple one-liner:

```
perl -p00e's/\R"[^"]*"//' file.txt
```

If you would like "safe" removing of quoted string you can use [`Text::Balanced`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced) standard module for generating regexp:

```
perl -MText::Balanced=gen_delimited_pat -p00e'BEGIN{$r=gen_delimited_pat(q{"})}s/\R$r//' file.txt
```

or insert generated (and simplified) output of `gen_delimited_pat`

```
perl -p00e's/\R"[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"//' file.txt
```

Comment: Why somebody downvoted my answer. Do you bother to describe what is wrong with this working example?

Comment: Upvoted. I have found that with these mixed regex/perl questions, you get a lot of people who do not know beyond what copied some place a long time ago, and downvote on the basis of that ignorance.